# Как создать React проект?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Создали проект через: `npm i react`

Как запустить проект?

Как лучше создавать проект на React?

Comment: `npm i react` не создает проект, а только устанавливает пакет, погуглите `create-react-app`

Comment: А можно ли создать из этого создать react приложение?

Answer (score 6):

В официальной документации [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) есть [отдельный раздел](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) в котором описываются способы создания нового React-приложения ([Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/), [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/), [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/), другие наборы инструментов и даже создание с нуля).

---

Для создания и дальнейшей разработки приложения *обычно* используют [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/).

Create React App — удобная среда для изучения React и лучший способ начать создание нового одностраничного приложения на React.

Инструмент настраивает среду для использования новейших возможностей JavaScript, оптимизирует приложение для продакшена и обеспечивает комфорт во время разработки.

Create React App не обрабатывает бэкенд логику или базы данных, он только предоставляет команды для сборки фронтенда, поэтому вы можете использовать его с любым бэкэндом. «Под капотом» используются Babel и webpack, но вам не нужно ничего знать о них.

Для создания проекта выполните команды:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Когда ваше приложение готово к развёртыванию в продакшене, запуск команды `npm run build` создаст оптимизированную сборку вашего приложения в папке build.

Comment: я немного дополнил ответ, ты не против?

Answer (score 1):

Заходите в директорию (свою папку), открываете консоль и указываете путь до этой папки (или в редакторе через терминал) и вводите туда `npx create-react-app my-app`
консоль будет спрашивать Вас, как назвать проект и т.п., все пропускаете нажав enter,
вводите в ту же консоль после установки cd my-app
и там же вводите npm start - сервер и приложение запустится

Comment: в конце точнее npm run start

Answer (score 0):

Если не хочется пользоваться `create-react-app`, то для простейшей интеграции React-a можно обойтись и без проекта. Просто подключить на сайте:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

(без `jsx`)